# Generate Attendance Details for an year using WPF Datagrid- What is the best way to do it?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using below code to get the year wise attendance dashboard details for an employee using wpf DataGrid.The actual problem is am pretty confused to bind the data with wpf datagrid columns.I want to generate all grid columns dynamically and bind the data into it.My requirement is display the days in column headers and every row data starting position should be based on the  1st day of month.Find the attached image for more clarity.

Shall i generate the Model for every column like FirstSunday,FirstMonday likewise these till Fifth Saturday of week to bind the column or is there any other way to do it easily.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Below code used to generate all days and month names with holiday details

```
   public class DashboardDateDetails
    {
        public bool IsHoliday { get; set; }
        public string DayName { get; set; }
        public string ShortDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string MonthWithYear { get; set; }
        public string ReasonForHoliday { get; set; }
    }
```

//Input parameter HolidaysList will hold the list of holidays in a year.This method would return the date and day with holiday details from 1st Jan to  31st Dec for a selected year.

```
private List<DashboardDateDetails> GetDashBoardData(List<KeyValuePair<string,DateTime>> HolidaysList)
{
    List<DashboardDateDetails> MonthList = new List<DashboardDateDetails>();
    int CurrentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
    DateTime FirstDateOfYear = new DateTime(CurrentYear,01,01);            
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
    string[] DayNames = Culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames;
    string[] MonthNames = Culture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames;
    string FirstDayNameOfYear = DayNames[(int)FirstDateOfYear.DayOfWeek];
    for (int MonthCount = 1; MonthCount <= 12; MonthCount++)
    {
        int NumberOfDaysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(CurrentYear, MonthCount);
        for (int DayCount = 1; DayCount <= NumberOfDaysInMonth; DayCount++)
        {                    
            DashboardDateDetails DateDetails = new DashboardDateDetails();
            DateTime CurrentDate = new DateTime(CurrentYear, MonthCount, DayCount);
            DateDetails.DayName = DayNames[(int)CurrentDate.DayOfWeek];
            DateDetails.Date = CurrentDate;
            DateDetails.ShortDate = CurrentDate.ToShortDateString();
            DateDetails.MonthWithYear = MonthNames[(int)CurrentDate.Month - 1];
            if (HolidaysList != null && HolidaysList.Any())
            {
                var HolidayDate = HolidaysList.Where(a => a.Value.ToShortDateString() == CurrentDate.ToShortDateString());
                DateDetails.IsHoliday = HolidayDate != null && HolidayDate.Any();
                DateDetails.ReasonForHoliday = HolidayDate != null && HolidayDate.Count() > 0 ? HolidayDate.First().Key : string.Empty;
            }
            MonthList.Add(DateDetails);
        }
    }
    return MonthList;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi the following implementation is not exactly same as you want but i hope it will give you an idea.I havent gone on style and all just want to give you an idea of logic.

> xaml

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="dataGrid" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding DashboardDates}"/>
```

> xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Creat datagrid columns.Can also be done in xaml. but for short i have done in .cs 
        CreateCoulmns();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }

    void CreateCoulmns()
    {
        var converter = new BackGroundConverter();
        for (int i = -1; i < 35; i++)
        {
            DataGridTextColumn dataGridTextColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();

            if (i == -1)
            {
                dataGridTextColumn.Header = "Month / Day";
                dataGridTextColumn.Binding = new Binding("MonthName");
            }
            else
            {
                switch (i % 7)
                {
                    case 0: dataGridTextColumn.Header = "Mo"; break;
                    case 1: dataGridTextColumn.Header = "Tu"; break;
                    case 2: dataGridTextColumn.Header = "We"; break;
                    case 3: dataGridTextColumn.Header = "Th"; break;
                    case 4: dataGridTextColumn.Header = "Fr"; break;
                    case 5: dataGridTextColumn.Header = "Sa"; break;
                    case 6: dataGridTextColumn.Header = "Su"; break;
                }
                dataGridTextColumn.Binding = new Binding(string.Format("Days[{0}].NumericDay", i));

                //Set BackGround property in style and use converter to set background according to HolidayType
                dataGridTextColumn.CellStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
                dataGridTextColumn.CellStyle.Setters.Add(
                    new Setter
                    {
                        Property = DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty,
                        Value = new Binding(string.Format("Days[{0}]", i)) { Converter = converter }

                    });
            }
            dataGrid.Columns.Add(dataGridTextColumn);

        }
    }
}
```

> Converter

```
public class BackGroundConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var day = value as Day;
        if (day != null)
        {
            //Dont use else if Like Saturday can be a restricted holiday so gray needs to be overridden by red.
            if (day.HolidayType == HolidayType.SatOrSun)
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
            if (day.HolidayType == HolidayType.RestrictedHoliday)
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            if (day.HolidayType == HolidayType.PublicHoilday)
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

> Custom Types

```
public enum HolidayType
{
    None,
    SatOrSun,
    PublicHoilday,
    RestrictedHoliday
}

public class Day
{
    public int? NumericDay { get; set; }

    public HolidayType HolidayType { get; set; }
}

public class DashboardDateDetails
{
    public string MonthName { get; set; }

    public List<Day> Days { get; set; }
}
```

> ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        DashboardDates = new List<DashboardDateDetails>();
        GenerateCalendar();
    }
    //This will be binded to ItemsSource
    public List<DashboardDateDetails> DashboardDates { get; set; }

    //Suppose these are Restricted Holidays
    List<DateTime> RestrictedHolidays = new List<DateTime>{
        new DateTime(2014,2,1),
        new DateTime(2014,3,5),
        new DateTime(2014,4,15),
        new DateTime(2014,6,2),
        new DateTime(2014,8,15),
        new DateTime(2014,11,25),
        new DateTime(2014,12,24)
    };

    //Suppose these are Public Holidays
    List<DateTime> PublicHolidays = new List<DateTime>{
        new DateTime(2014,2,1),
        new DateTime(2014,3,15),
        new DateTime(2014,4,19),
        new DateTime(2014,6,20),
        new DateTime(2014,8,11),
        new DateTime(2014,11,12),
        new DateTime(2014,12,25)
    };

    void GenerateCalendar()
    {
        //Lop for 12 months
        for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++)
        {
            //firstdate for month.This will help to get the first day of month
            var firstdate = new DateTime(2014, month, 1);

            //Get the first date index
            int firstDateIndex = (int)firstdate.DayOfWeek;
            //In DayOfWeek enum first day is Sunday but we want Monday so decrement the index
            firstDateIndex--;

            //Restricted holidays for this month
            var restrictedHolidays = RestrictedHolidays.Where(s => s.Month == month);

            //Public holidays for this month
            var publicHolidays = PublicHolidays.Where(s => s.Month == month);

            //Instance of DashboardDateDetails
            DashboardDateDetails details = new DashboardDateDetails
            {
                MonthName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(month),
                Days = new Day[40].ToList()  //Create an array of capacity 40
            };

            for (int j = 1; j <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(2014, month); j++)
            {
                int index = 0;

                if (firstDateIndex < 0)
                    index = j - 1;
                else
                    index = j + firstDateIndex - 1;

                var day = new Day { NumericDay = j };
                //is sat or sun
                if (((index % 7) == 6) || ((index % 7) == 5))
                    day.HolidayType = HolidayType.SatOrSun;
                //is restricted holiday
                if (restrictedHolidays.Any(s => s.Day == index))
                    day.HolidayType = HolidayType.RestrictedHoliday;
                //is public holiday
                if (publicHolidays.Any(s => s.Day == index))
                    day.HolidayType = HolidayType.PublicHoilday;

                details.Days[index] = day;
            }

            DashboardDates.Add(details);
        }
    }

}
```

> Output [image]

I hope this will help you to give an idea.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable solution.I was struggling in dynamic binding.Got an idea now.Index value needs to be updated as index = j+5 instead of index = j - 1 to display the month which are starting on sundays.Great !!!!!